# Is it possible to translate a custom App's description? If so, how?

Tags: managed-package, lightning-apps, translation, translation-workbench

Background:

I have a managed package with a custom app in it. I want to have the app description automatically translate to match the selected language of the user like how custom labels work. Using `Translation workbench->translate` I was able to easily find and translate the name of my app, but oddly, I haven't seen a way to translate the description.

My Question:

Is it possible to translate a custom App's description? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

More than a year later and there still doesn't seem to be any ability to do this. I created an Idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000ULHBQA4) and would appreciate the upvote if you never found a solution to this.
Given the lack of others enquiring about this I'm not sure it's a feature that would be in-demand, but it might be a quick addition seeing as the App Label can be translated.

Comment: This answer supports "no it is not possible", which is inherently difficult to prove or cite references to. An idea requesting the feature is sufficient evidence here.